# VHDL - Shift operation of N times with concatenation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, concatenation, vhdl, bit-shift

I would like to know how can I do a shift operation in VHDL if I have 2 inputs, one input, DATA1 is a number (std_logic_vector), and the second input DATA2 represents the number of times I want to shift the first input. 
For example, if I must shift left always only one time, the code is

```
OUTALU <= '0' & DATA1(N-1 downto 1);
```

If I would like to shift DATA2 times, is it right writing:

```
for i in 0 to DATA2 loop
  OUTALU <= '0' & DATA1(N-1 downto 1);
  DATA1 <= OUTALU
end loop;
```

is it right?
I must define signals and assign to these signals DATA1 and DATA2?
Thank you for help

Comment: take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seek is a barrel-shifter. You can do that like this:

```
OUTALU <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(DATA1),  to_integer(unsigned(DATA2)))); -- Shift left
OUTALU <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(DATA1),  to_integer(unsigned(DATA2)))); -- Shift right
OUTALU <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(  signed(DATA1),  to_integer(unsigned(DATA2)))); -- Arithmetic shift left
OUTALU <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(  signed(DATA1),  to_integer(unsigned(DATA2)))); -- Arithmetic shift right
```

This implies you use `ieee.numeric_std.all' and that`DATA1`and`DATA2` are *std_logic_vector*, thus the casts.

Comment: shift_left is already implement function? Is a logical or arithmetic shift?

Comment: It is implemented in numeric_std. If the input is `unsigned`, it is a logical shift. On the other hand, it performs arithmetic shift when the inout is `signed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
datao <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data1) sll to_integer(unsigned(data2)));
```

sll is shift left logical, filled with ‘0’

you can also use sla (shift left arithmetic, filled with right bit) instead sll.

ps: datao <= '0' & data1(7 downto 1) is a right shifter, not left :).
use srl or sra.

Comment: The use of sll, sla, and cie is discouraged in favor of shift_left/shift_right. The operators were not defined properly and can lead to unexpected behaviour, such as sla will copying the sign bit to the lsb!