# What does SHR stand for in VHDL and how do you use it to shift to a number of bits

Tags: vhdl

What does the "SHR" stand for, am i right to assume that in "VHDL" it means shift to the right by 16 bits?
My second question is how would i shift this to the right by 10 bits or to be honest by any btis

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for **sh**ift right/left. It shifts for the specified amount of bits, not a constant 16 as you assumed.

These functions are defined for *signed* and *unsigned*. The problem is, it is defined in the library `IEEE.std_logic_arith`, which is not part of the VHDL standard. The equivalent standard library is `IEEE.numeric_std`, which defines `shift_left` and `shift_right`.

As MTCoster suggested, you can look up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left).

Comment: The code that is in question is printed at the bottom;
CURRENT_OUTPUT <= SHR(("100101001110" * CURRENT_INPUT + "100101001110" * LAST_INPUT1 +
"1110110101100011" * LAST_OUTPUT1), "10000");

Comment: @bahjat I am sorry, what is this comment for?