# I'm getting an error while using sll

Tags: vhdl

The problem is that I wanna use this `sll` command but am getting this error (in the pic). I know the

```
bp := bp(0 to 6) & '0';
```

statement, but I still wanna use  this sll. Can anyone help?

Error line:
5th from the last

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std;

entity mul is
  port(
    a, b : in  std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
    c    : out std_logic_vector(0 to 7));
end mul;

architecture mul of mul is
begin
  process(a, b)
    variable bp, p : std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
  begin
    bp := "0000"&b;
    p  := "00000000";

    for k in 0 to 3 loop
      if a(k) = '1' then
        p := p + bp;
      end if;
      bp := bp sll 1;
    end loop;
    c <= p;
  end process;
end mul;
```

Comment: What 'pic' pray tell?

Comment: The error you received isn't in evidence here. If you have access to a -2008 compliant VHDL tool, substituting a use clause containing IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned for use clauses containing Synopsys package std_logic_arith and IEEE package numeric_std would allow your code to analyze, elaborate and simulate (without commenting on it's accuracy). Package numeric_std_unsigned allows you to treat std_logic_vector objects as if they were unsigned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shift a std\_logic\_vector of n bit to right or left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing the non-standard VHDL (Synopsys) `std_logic_unsigned` package and the standard VHDL `numeric_std` package is likely to lead to undesired results, so my suggestion is to use only the standard VHDL `numeric_std` package using only:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

With this you can then do:

```
if a(k) = '1' then
  p := std_logic_vector(unsigned(p) + unsigned(bp));
end if;
bp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(bp) sll 1);
```

The `"sll"` function from `numeric_std` package is then used as infix operator, and this is the same as writing:

```
bp := std_logic_vector("sll"(unsigned(bp), 1));
```

Note that for a shift amount of 1, it is the same as writing:

```
bp := std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(bp), 1));
```

The last statement using the `shift_left` function is suggested, since the `sll` operator in VHDL may not always work as "expected" before VHDL-2008 (read more
[here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bit-shifts-in-vhdl.html)), so using the `shift_left` function from the `numeric_std` package ensures readability and expected operation across different VHDL versions.

Comment: Or use IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned instead, for a -2008 compliant tool chain.

Comment: @user1155120: How come `sll` or `shl` is not defined in `numeric_std_unsigned` for `(std_logic_vector, integer)`?  Only `shl(std_logic_vector, std_logic_vector)` is defined.

Comment: In -2008, std_logic_vector is a subtype of std_ulogic_vector and std_logic_1164 declares sll and srl for [std_ulogic_vector, integer return std_ulogic_vector].