# VHDL arithmetic shift_left

Tags: vhdl

With the `shift_left` function of `ieee.numeric_std`, I want to shift a signal to left and insert `1` or `0` from the right.

```
signal qo: signed (3 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
qo <= shift_left(qo,1);
```

That will only insert `0` from right. I want to insert `1` upon some conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `shift_left` function, how about using *slicing* and *concatenation*:

```
qo <= qo(2 downto 0) & '1';
```

or

```
qo <= qo(2 downto 0) & '0';
```

Personally, I recommend using slicing and concatenation for shifts and rotates. There are issues with the operators (`sra` etc) and, as you can see, using slicing and concatenation gives you complete control.

Comment: OK. According to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left it is said to be good to use nmeric_std since it allows a lot of functions and methods to ease the coding.

Comment: @mahmood Well, it's up to you and depends on what you mean by "ease the coding".

Answer (score 1):

Inserting `'1'` at the rightmost position of a signal of type `signed` means incrementing its value by 1. Likewise, *not* inserting `'1'` means incrementing its value by 0.

This is best expressed by the `+` operator which is [overloaded by the `numeric_std` package](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/numeric_std.vhdl):

> ```
> -- Id: A.8
> function "+" (L: SIGNED; R: INTEGER) return SIGNED;
> -- Result subtype: SIGNED(L'LENGTH-1 downto 0).
> -- Result: Adds a SIGNED vector, L, to an INTEGER, R.
> ```

So simply use:

```
shift_left(qo, 1) + 1
```

respectively

```
shift_left(qo, 1) + 0
```

This works irrespective of how `qo` is defined, so if you later change the length of `qo` you don't need to adjust any slicing operations.

Comment: This is a clever trick! I personally find it a bit less intuitive. To fix your issue with the selected answer, you could use a VHDL tick attribute `'left` to make `qo` flexible, like `qo <= qo(qo'left downto 0);`