# Type error messsage in VHDL while applying arithmetic shift

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;


entity ALU is 

    generic (
            constant N: natural :=1
            );
            
        Port (
        A,B :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        ALU_Sel :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        ALU_Out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        Carryout : out std_logic
        );
    end ALU;
    
    
    architecture Behavioral of ALU is

signal ALU_Result : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal tmp: std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);

begin
   process(A,B,ALU_Sel)
 begin
  case(ALU_Sel) is
  when "000" => -- Addition
   ALU_Result <= A + B ; 
  when "001" => -- Subtraction
   ALU_Result <= A - B ;
    when "010" => -- Logical And 
    ALU_Result <= A and B;
    when "011" => --Logical Or
    ALU_Result <= A or B;   
    when "100" => --Arithmetic shift left A
    
    ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) sla N);
    when "101" => --Arithmetic shift right A
    
    ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) sra N);
    when "110" => --Circular shift left
    ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) rol N);
    when "111" => --Circular shift right
    ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) ror N);
    
    end case;
    
    end process;
    ALU_Out <= ALU_Result; -- ALU Out
    tmp <= ('0' & A) + ('0' & B);
    Carryout <= tmp(8); -- Carryout Flag
    
    end Behavioral;
```

Hello guys, my code gives type error. In line 40 and 42 are being used for the arithmetic shift. But those 2 codes are only for signed bits and are being used for the variables for bit vectores. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Could you please help me?

Comment: Why not use the signed type instead?

Comment: I use signed type, the other operators are being broken.

Comment: instead of `ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) sla N);` why not do `ALU_Result <= std_logic_vector(signed(A) sla N);` ?

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035788/5491952